# How did Truman's father parachute into the set?

Tags: the-truman-show

In the Truman Show, we see Truman's father parachute into the set, presumably against Christof's wishes.

Considering the set is an enclosed dome, is it ever explained how he got there?

[image]

Comment: That wasn't Truman's father.

Comment: Presumably the dome has service entrances which perhaps weren't as carefully guarded as they should have been.

Answer (score 23):

That wasn't Truman's father, it was an anti-Truman Show activist called William Griffin. He later joined Lauren's *Free Truman Alliance*.

Apparently he was able gain access to a lighting gantry and BASE-jumped onto the Seahaven set.

> There have been dozens of documented attempts to "liberate" Truman. One of the most spectacular was the parachute jump from a lighting gantry in the twenty-eighth season by William Griffin, better known as "Billie Blackbird." Unfortunately for Billie, Truman turned his head at the critical moment and missed seeing the sign Billie was wearing — **"TRUMAN, YOU'RE ON TV."**
>
> The sky diver was quickly bundled out of sight. Billie later sued, claiming studio security guards tried to strangle him with his own rip cord, but a judge threw out the case stating, "*If you try to jeopardize a major television show, there are consequences.*"
>
> <sub><sup>[Truman Show: The Shooting Script](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/280031.The_Truman_Show)</sup></sub>